# How to put arrows on boundary circles in the tqft package

Tags: tikz-pgf, tqft

I'm drawing some simple cobordisms with tikz and tqft. I would like to indicate the orientation of the incoming and outgoing circles by putting arrowheads on them. Is there a simple way to do that?

Code, I'm using is e.g.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tqft}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tqft/flow=east]
\node[tqft, incoming boundary components=1,
outgoing boundary components=1,draw, boundary lower style={dashed,draw}] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces (though in better resolution):

[image: A cylinder]

The kind of arrow I would like to have is like in this picture (only the light green part)[image]

Comment: Will this element be part of a larger `tikz` picture, or is it a standalone graphic (sans arrows)?

Comment: I'm not sure where you are heading. I want to use this picture, but also others. For example, I'll be using a pair of pants as well. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I guess I'm asking whether you are restricting solutions to those that use *only* `tikz`, or whether arrows can be attached elsewise?  If you wait a few minutes, I'll post an answer, and you can reject it, if it doesn't suit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution within tikz and tqft. It makes use of the nodes provided within the tqft-package: The whole cobordism is a node called "a". It has subnodes "a.incoming boundary n" where n enumerates the incoming boundary circles and similarly for the outgoing ones.

Unfortunately the displacement is found by hand and having no idea about the inner workings of tikz I don't know how it responds to scaling or anything.
A nice touch would definitely be to have an option in the tqft package that puts these little arrows on the circles.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[tqft/flow=east]
  \node[tqft, incoming boundary components=1,
  outgoing boundary components=1,draw, boundary lower style={dashed,draw}](a) at (0,0) {};
  \node at ($(a.incoming boundary 1)+(-0.166,0)$) {$\wedge$};
  \node at ($(a.outgoing boundary 1)+(-0.172,0)$) {$\vee$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: The boundary circles are nodes in their own right so you can use the angle anchors to avoid doing the calculations.  Thus `\node at (a incoming 1.90) {$\wedge$};  \node at (a outgoing 1.90) {$\vee$};` would put them at the right places.

Answer (score 4):

I have uploaded a new version of [`tqft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tqft) to CTAN (7th April 2014).  Once this propagates through the system, then the following code will work and will put arrows on the upper arcs of the boundary circles.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166698/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tqft,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every tqft/.style={transform shape},rotate=90]
  \pic[
  tqft,
  incoming boundary components=1,
  outgoing boundary components=1,
  draw,
  every lower boundary component/.style={draw},
  every incoming lower boundary component/.style={dashed,draw},
  every outgoing upper boundary component/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{>}},
    },
  },
  every incoming upper boundary component/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position .5 with {\arrowreversed{>}},
    },
  },
  name=a
];
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that this requires TikZ3.0 (or later).  Also, the way to load the package is now as a TikZ library, not as a separate style file.

You might want bigger arrows, but that's a separate issue.

[image: TQFT with arrows]

Answer (score 3):

REVISED ANSWER (see original answer below for description of method)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tqft, graphicx, stackengine}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\def\figraw{\begin{tikzpicture}[tqft/flow=east]
\node[tqft, incoming boundary components=1,
outgoing boundary components=1,draw, boundary lower style={dashed,draw}] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\savestack{\fig}{\figraw}
\def\OUT{-1.60pt}
\def\IN{8.03pt}
\def\WW{1.5pt}
\def\VV{-1.5pt}
\def\VEE{\scalebox{0.6}{$\vee$}}
\def\WEDGE{\scalebox{0.6}{$\wedge$}}
\stackinset{r}{\IN}{c}{\VV}{\VEE}{\fig}\par
\stackinset{l}{\OUT}{c}{\VV}{\VEE}{%
  \stackinset{r}{\IN}{c}{\WW}{\WEDGE}{%
    \fig%
}}\par
\stackinset{l}{\OUT}{c}{\WW}{\WEDGE}{%
  \stackinset{r}{\IN}{c}{\VV}{\VEE}{%
    \fig%
}}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

And since I went through the effort to parametrize it, to allow syntax such as `\LeftSideArrow\setoutside\uppointing{\fig}`, I show that code here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tqft, graphicx, stackengine}
\parskip 1ex
%
\def\OUT{-1.60pt}
\def\IN{8.03pt}
\def\WW{1.5pt}
\def\VV{-1.5pt}
\def\VEE{\scalebox{0.6}{$\vee$}}
\def\WEDGE{\scalebox{0.6}{$\wedge$}}
%
\def\LeftSideArrowHelper{\stackinset{l}}
\def\RightSideArrowHelper{\stackinset{r}}
\def\setinside{\IN}
\def\setoutside{\OUT}
\def\uppointing{{c}{\WW}{\WEDGE}}
\def\downpointing{{c}{\VV}{\VEE}}
\def\LeftSideArrow{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\LeftSideArrowHelper\expandafter}
\def\RightSideArrow{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\RightSideArrowHelper\expandafter}

\begin{document}
\def\figraw{\begin{tikzpicture}[tqft/flow=east]
    \node[tqft, incoming boundary components=1,
    outgoing boundary components=1,draw, boundary lower style={dashed,draw}] at (0,0) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\savestack{\fig}{\figraw}

\LeftSideArrow\setoutside\uppointing{%
  \RightSideArrow\setinside\downpointing{%
    \fig}}
\end{document}
```

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER (prior to OP posting an image)

Here, I work outside of `tikz` to establish the arrows.  I instead use `\stackinset`.  I first show various use cases using the raw `\stackinset` syntax.  But if this were to be a common occurrence, the usage could be parametrized, as I show at the end of my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tqft, graphicx, stackengine}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\def\fig{\begin{tikzpicture}[tqft/flow=east]
\node[tqft, incoming boundary components=1,
outgoing boundary components=1,draw, boundary lower style={dashed,draw}] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\stackinset{r}{-18pt}{c}{-1.8pt}{\scalebox{2.5}{$\rightarrow$}}{\fig}\par
\stackinset{r}{-18pt}{c}{-1.8pt}{\scalebox{2.5}{$\leftarrow$}}{\fig}\par
\stackinset{r}{3pt}{c}{-1.8pt}{\scalebox{2.5}{$\leftarrow$}}{\fig}\par
\stackinset{l}{3pt}{c}{-1.8pt}{\scalebox{2.5}{$\leftarrow$}}{%
  \stackinset{r}{-18pt}{c}{-1.8pt}{\scalebox{2.5}{$\leftarrow$}}{%
    \fig%
}}\par
\stackinset{l}{-18pt}{c}{-1.8pt}{\scalebox{2.5}{$\rightarrow$}}{%
  \stackinset{r}{-18pt}{c}{-1.8pt}{\scalebox{2.5}{$\rightarrow$}}{%
    \fig%
}}\par
If this element were used often, it could be parameterized:
\def\LeftArrow{{\scalebox{2.5}{$\leftarrow$}}}
\def\RightArrow{{\scalebox{2.5}{$\rightarrow$}}}
\edef\insideleft{{l}{3pt}{c}{-1.8pt}}
\edef\outsideleft{{l}{-18pt}{c}{-1.8pt}}
\edef\insideright{{r}{3pt}{c}{-1.8pt}}
\edef\outsideright{{r}{-18pt}{c}{-1.8pt}}
\def\MakeArrow{\expandafter\stackinset}

\MakeArrow\outsideleft\LeftArrow{%
\MakeArrow\outsideright\RightArrow{%
\fig%
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If the `tikz` image is used over and over again, it saves time to make it once and box it.  Thus, in that case, the `\def\fig{...}` in my MWE could be replaced by

```
\def\figraw{\begin{tikzpicture}[tqft/flow=east]
\node[tqft, incoming boundary components=1,
outgoing boundary components=1,draw, boundary lower style={dashed,draw}] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\savestack{\fig}{\figraw}
```

Then, `\fig` would be available as a ready-made box, containing the contents of `\figraw`.

---

If one wanted a different arrow style, the stealth arrow glyphs could be imported from `mathabx`, by inserting this into your preamble:

```
% Setup the matha font (from mathabx.sty)
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}

% Define a subset character from that font (from mathabx.dcl)
% to completely replace the \subset character, you can replace
% \varsubset with \subset

\DeclareMathSymbol{\varleftarrow}{3}{matha}{"D0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrightarrow}{3}{matha}{"D1}
```

Then, using `\varleftarrow` and `\varrightarrow`, instead of `\leftarrow` and `\rightarrow`, would yield, for example, something like this:

[image]

Comment: Oohhh... I'm very sorry, that I caused you so much work. Thats not, what I had in mind. I honestly didn't think of your interpretation. I'll add a picture of what I had in mind.

Comment: @Eike A vortex, a vortex, my kingdom for a vortex!  Oh well.

Comment: @Eike Please see revision.

Comment: In the end I couldn't adapt it to other cobordisms. Luckily I found this dirty but simple way below.

Comment: @Eike Glad you got it resolved.